# How can i use volume in my dockerfile for copy the jmeter result in my local

Tags: docker, jmeter, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can I use volume in my dockerfile for copy the JMeter result in my local?
Need to display the result in local, how can I copy the result and paste in local with the help of VOLUME.

For example:- I am saving the JMeter HTML report in my container but after that container is automatically stopped. So someone suggests me to use the docker VOLUME command for RUN the HTML.

```
FROM alpine

ARG JMETER_VERSION="4.0"
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN  ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL  https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-functions/2.0/jmeter-plugins-functions-2.0.jar
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/ext/


# Change TimeZone TODO: TZ still is not set!
ARG TZ="Australia/Melbourne"
RUN    apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apk add --update openjdk8-jre tzdata curl unzip bash \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/dependencies  \
    && curl -L --silent ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} >  /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz  \
    && mkdir -p /opt  \
    && tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt  \
    && rm -rf /tmp/dependencies

RUN curl -L --silent ${JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL}/jmeter-plugins-dummy/0.2/jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.2.jar -o ${JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER}/jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.2.jar
RUN curl -L --silent ${JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL}/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter/0.5/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.5.jar -o ${JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER}/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.5.jar

# TODO: plugins (later)
# && unzip -oq "/tmp/dependencies/JMeterPlugins-*.zip" -d $JMETER_HOME

# Set global PATH such that "jmeter" command is found
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN

ENV URL_PATH=${URL}

WORKDIR ${JMETER_HOME} 

#RUN export DATETIME=$(date +%Y%m%d)

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/"$(date +%Y%m%d)"

VOLUME /var/www/html/

#Copy the *.jmx file jmeter bin file 
COPY Get_Ping_Node_API.jmx ./bin

CMD ./bin/jmeter -n -t ./bin/Get_Ping_Node_API.jmx -l ./bin/result.jtl -e -o ./bin/result_html'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker volume while you run the docker image.
You can add --volume , -v flag to your docker run command.

> docker run -v "HOST DIR":"CONTAINER DIR"